# Sqlite Transaction - When Does Reserve Lock Take Effect

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions

I was wondering at point after issuing a SqliteConnection BeginTransaction() call does the Reserve Lock engage and start blocking writes ?

Does the Reserve Lock correspond to the actual BeginTransaction call, or is it only after Commit is called and the transaction run ?

I ask b/c, in order to leverage my existing data access layer, and not have to write custom transactions everytime I need one to prevent a race condition, I wan't to make a call to BeginTransaction(), and then call any combination of existing Select/Insert/Update wrappers to solve a problem at hand, while having exclusive write access, then finally call a Commit.  In order to prevent the race conditions I'm trying to avoid, I would require that the reserve lock on the transaction is active "immediately" upon calling BeginTransaction (ie, sometime before it returns).

If more clarification or details are needed, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide them.  Thank ya's kindly for your expertise.

Comment: This answer here: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1157/4892.aspx addresses this issue, though b/c of lack of any other documentation on this, some confirmation of this fact or some more details regarding it would be nice.  Proceeding with my aforemntioned solution above, significant modification of my DAL will be required and so would like to know with confidence how the locks work wrt BeginTransaction/Commit.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

> The first read operation against a database creates a SHARED lock and the first write operation creates a RESERVED lock.

When all changes fit into the page cache, the first actual write operation will happen during the `COMMIT`.

To force SQLite to take a lock when executing the `BEGIN`, start the transaction with `BEGIN IMMEDIATE`:

> After a BEGIN IMMEDIATE, no other database connection will be able to write to the database or do a BEGIN IMMEDIATE or BEGIN EXCLUSIVE. Other processes can continue to read from the database, however.

If you want to prevent reads (which should not be necessary as all transactions are properly serialized in any case), use `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE`.

Comment: This is such good news... Things were looking grim after writing my first "custom transaction" (really, really ugly). I'll surely test it an a side app, but I dont have time now as this race condition has consumed almost two weeks of development!  Thanks so much for this gem.

Comment: CL. - I was wondering what isolation level corresponds to "BEGIN IMMEDIATE" being used by the transaction ?  The SqliteCommand method BeginTransaction() takes an Isolation Level as its parameter, and I think this value determines which lock mode the transaction will use (ie, BEGIN IMMEDIATE, BEGIN EXCLUSIVE, ...). Unless I missing something here, thanks. ref: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/1281.aspx

Comment: SQLite's transactions are always serializable.

Comment: @CL, not true when in WAL mode.